# Why I get this wrong output?

Tags: c, list

I created this simple double linked list.
The problem is that when I print all its elements, they have the same char value even if the variable "a" changes every time.

```
typedef struct node{
char *name;
struct node *n;
struct node *p;
} N;

N *h=NULL;//head

void insert(char *value){
N *temp=malloc(sizeof(N));
if(h==NULL){
    h=temp;
    temp->name=strdup(value);
}
else{
    N *curr=h;
    while(curr->n!=NULL)
        curr=curr->n;
    curr->n=temp;
    temp->p=curr;
    temp->name=strdup(value);
}
}

void print(){
N *temp=h;
printf("%s\n", temp->name);
while(temp->n!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n", temp->name);
    temp=temp->n;
}
}


int main(){

char a[...];
fgets(a,...)

//there is a while section: every time i enter in it, there is:
char *input=a;
insert(input);
print();
}
```

So I expected something as:
Lion
Bear
Goat
....
Instead i get:
Lion, then
Bear
Bear, then
Goat
Goat
Goat

etc...

Comment: your code is incomplete.  where is value coming from ?  do you  allocate memory for every node->name ?

Comment: @bigdataolddriver sorry, value is the function parameter

Comment: In the insert function you also need to set n and p to NULL in the h == NULL case.

Comment: @jmq i tried, but nothing changed

Comment: @emisk Can you update the question with your current code?  This will help us troubleshoot it with you.

Comment: just done!
now the problem is that: the input is Lion Bear Goat Tiger Cat and the output is Lion Lion Bear Goat Tiger

Comment: @jmq ok, changing the print function with "printf(..., temp->n->name)" works... but why? :/

Comment: @emisk Lion is printed twice because you print the first value, and then print the first value again the first time you go through the while loop.  See my solution below.  Good Luck!

Comment: @emisk  Why did you remove all the code from your question and try to remove all the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.  First you have a bug in print() that prevents the last value from being displayed.  Check temp instead of temp->n:

```
void print()
{
    N *temp=h;

    while(temp !=NULL){
       printf("%s\n", temp->name);
       temp=temp->n;
   }
}
```

Your extra printf() call (before the while loop) is why the first value was printed twice.

Also you must assign p and n when you add a new node.  You can't assume that they will be NULL if you don't assign them.

```
void insert(char *value)
{
    N *temp=malloc(sizeof(N));
    if(h==NULL){
        h=temp;
        temp->p = NULL;
        temp->n = NULL;
        temp->name=strdup(value);
    }
    else{
        N *curr=h;
        while(curr->n!=NULL)
        curr=curr->n;
        curr->n=temp;
        temp->p=curr;
        temp->n = NULL;
        temp->name=strdup(value);
   }
}
```

Also, do you need the list to be double-linked?  You never use the p pointer.

Comment: @emisk You only traverse the list in one direction so all the references to ->p can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing to the same memory for each list element.  This code

```
temp->name=value;
```

merely copies the **value of the pointer** to `temp->name` because of the definition of the structure:

```
typedef struct node{
char *name;
struct node *n;
struct node *p;
} N;
```

`name` is just a pointer.  You need to duplicate the string that `value` points to, not just point `name` at `value` (input validation and error checking are left as an exercise for the reader...):

```
char *duplicateString( const char *inputString )
{
    char newString = malloc( strlen( inputString ) + 1 );
    strcpy( newString, inputString );
    return( newString );
}
```

so

```
temp->name = duplicateString( value );
```

Just remember to call `free( temp->name )` before you call `free( temp )` to free your node.

or [just use `strdup()` if you're on a POSIX system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html):

```
temp->name = strdup( value );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I made the change you suggest ( temp->name = strdup( value ); in the insert function), but now:
when I first input Lion, I get Lion (ok), then when I input Bear, I get Lion Lion, then when input Goat, I get Lion Lion Bear... I can't figure out it

Comment: an alternative way is to  change the struct definition from "char *name" to "char name[32]"  .  the number 32  can be changed to the reasonable number that fgets accepts to limit input string size , when the input strings are known to be short , this way could save a lot of malloc and free calling pair.

Comment: If it's possible, I'd like to try to keep that structure for efficiency reasons (memory)...
Can we figure out why it is printing the precedent name?
as I said before, now the input is: Lion Bear Goat Tiger Cat
and the output is: Lion Lion Bear Goat Tiger

Comment: @bigdataolddriver ok, changing the print function with "printf(..., temp->n->name)" works... but why? :/